# Call stored procedure or run sql query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible yet to execute a stored procedure or execute a piece of SQL in EF7?

To do this in earlier EF versions we have a variety of options such as those detailed on [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

If not is there a plan to allow this through one of the Extension namespaces (eg EntityFramework.Relational or EntityFramework.SqlServer).

At the moment I'm making this call via straight Ado.Net, however that has the disadvantage that it isn't (currently) supported by the dnxcore50 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it returns entities, use the `.FromSql()` extension method on `DbSet`. You can even continue composing LINQ on top of it.

```
var customers = db.Customers
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM Customer")
    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't using an entity at this point, however I've added a dummy entity to make use of this function - its a bit dirty, but much better than the repercussions of dropping to Ado. Its also worth noting that stored procs are a no-go here due to the sub querying - I converted mine to a TVF and all is good!

Answer (score 2):

Stored Procedures has not yet implemented in Entity Framework 7,you can track the development [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245).

Thanks

Comment: Cheers - unfortunately that's not really moved since last may 2014 - still on the backlog.